# How to change Chromium's default fallback for sans-serif, serif and monospace on Windows

Tags: css, windows, fonts, chromium

I see some pages specify the font family like

```
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
```

I know that on Linux, the browser respects the rules in "fonts.conf" to determine what font to use when Arial is not available or there are codepoints which Arial doesn't support, but I have no idea how I can customize it on Windows. On Windows it always falls back to a system font which I cannot control. (More specifically, on my Simplified Chinese system, it always falls back to SimSun.)

Interestingly, I found Firefox and Chrome treats font-family in a very different way.

For example, I substituted "Hiragino Sans GB" (which I don't have) with "XHei WP" (which I have installed) in the registry (`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes`). It works for Firefox, because when the CSS goes like "Hiragino Sans GB, Microsoft YaHei", Firefox uses "XHei WP" (follows the substitution rules in registry), but Chrome uses "Microsoft YaHei" (ignores the substitution rules).

Another difference that's related to this question is that, Firefox sees the fonts in the options as the last resort while Chrome, if any font is specified in "font-family", fallbacks to the system font...

I'm really puzzled with that and wonder if there's a way to customize the fallback rules of Chromium or the rules of Windows in a way Chromium respects. Thanks.

Comment: From the view of web design, you will always specify a font stack for a website, because you don't know what the default system font will be. You can't rely on it, because the manufacturer or user may have done changes you won't expect… So why you are you putting effort in this topic?

Comment: I'm not writing the pages. I just took some snippets on the existing pages as examples. What I am wishing to change is the "display effect" on my Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome extension Stylus, you can override the `font-family` style in css. Include the font you desire so Chrome does not use the fall-back font by system default. It is also helpful if you can search for any existing `font-family` styles in the element inspector.